# Trying to understand but getting mixed opinions

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, ambiguity, legalese

Here is the sentence I'm trying to understand:

> "Your contract and verbal agreement are hereby terminated sixty days after service upon you of this notice or as of November 26th, 2017, whichever is later.

So are they saying that the contract is terminated 60 days after service of the notice OR (sixty days) as of November 26th whichever is later. Or that it is terminated November 26th? I would think that they are saying that it is 60 days after service or 60 days after November 26th, whichever is later. If November 26 was going to be the last day, wouldn't it have to come before the "OR" i.e. - *are hereby terminated as of November 26th* or *as of sixty days after service upon you of this notice*.

When I ask around, it seems to be split down the middle on what it means, half the people I ask say 60 days after November 26 the other half say November 26th is when it ends...how does this sentence work? What is it stating?

Thank you in advance for the help on this.

Comment: It's not the clearest wording, but I'm fairly sure it's either (a) 60 days after service or (b) ON 26 November. I base that on the fact that it says (1) "sixty days after service" OR (2) **as of** November 26th. For the alternative reading you would have to read "sixty days *after as of* November 26th" - which does not make sense and is not standard language.  Of course, the interpretation may depend on which English-speaking country you are in!

Comment: Having given you an answer, I have to propose your Q. for closure, because interpreting legal documents is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it involves interpreting a legal document.

Comment: Of course it is a legal document: it is terminating a contract. If you don’t think the answers you have got are “conclusive” then your only option is to ask the sender of the letter.

Comment: Heh heh. There's room for a line about "a lawyer in my pjamas" but it's vague.

Answer (score 3):

There are two dates:

1. November 26, 2018.
2. 60 days after being served notice.

Whichever is *later* is the date on which the contract is terminated.

---

There are several points of ambiguity. None of them can be answered from the information currently provided:

- What is the date of "service upon you"—at what date does the 60-day period start? The date on the letter? The date it is actually received in the mail? The date a process server hands you the letter? How does either party *prove* the "service" date?
- How is *60 days later* counted? Business days or calendar days?
- At what time *during* the day of termination does the contract actually terminate?

---

Two examples:

- I am served notice on April 30, 2019.
  60 days after is June 30, 2019.
  June 30, 2019 is *later* than November 26, 2018.
  → My contract expires on June 30, 2019.
- I am served notice on April 30, 2018.
  60 days later is June 30, 2018.
  November 26, 2018 is *later* than June 30, 2018.
  → My contract expires on November 26, 2018.